# How to check codition in ng-show angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to hide a button when the other tag value is 'DONE'
here is my code `ng-show="{{transaction.status}}!='DONE'` But it does not work.
Please help me to fix it

Comment: just lose the curly braces.   transaction.satus !== 'DONE'

Answer (score 2):

Try the code:

```
ng-show="transaction.status !== 'DONE'"
```

or

```
ng-hide="transaction.status === 'DONE'"
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-show needs an expression. So it should be in "{{}}"

```
ng-show="{{ transaction.status !== 'DONE'}}"
```